# codenmaeone3.3 does not support JDK 1.8 collection filter

Tags: java, java-8, codenameone

I was trying to filter collection object using filter method of collections.

```
filterJobList = jobList.stream()
                .filter(j -> j.getJobStatus().equalsIgnoreCase(filterStatus))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I can run this code on simulator but in console it throws error:

> error: illegal start of expression:
>   `filter(j -> j.getJobStatus().equalsIgnoreCase(filterStatus))`

Does codenameone3.3 fully allow to use JDK1.8 methods ?

Comment: Hi this link is not the same but may be useful as the functionality you are trying to get is some what 'complex' in term of cross platform development support (like in CN1) see response here : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/codenameone-discussions/akash$20kubavat/codenameone-discussions/u9sviu5j8WY/2dihc5vxTzsJ

I may be wrong, but just guessing its similar depth of functionality..

Answer (score 1):

No. Streams are one of the features that we [specifically didn't support](http://www.codenameone.com/blog/java-8-support.html) from Java 8.

It's possible to add streams but the main issue with them would be performance. They would perform significantly worse on mobile devices than other alternatives thus negating a major reason for their inclusion.

If there is real community demand for streams support we might add this in the future.